# Calculating the volume of an elliptical region

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem**:

Calculate the volume of the finite body $K$ that is limited by the surfaces

$$
z=2-x^2-y^2
\\z=y^2
$$

[image: K visualized]

**Answer**: $\pi\sqrt2$

**My Attempt**:

The surfaces intersect when $x^2+2y^2 = 2$

Therefore, the volume is:

$$
\iint_{A}(2-x^2-y^2)-(y^2)=\iint_{A}2-x^2-2y^2
$$

where $A : x^2+2y^2 \le 2$.

The variable substitution
$$
u = x
\\v = \sqrt2y
$$

transforms the ellipsis into a circle, and $\frac{d(x, y)}{d(u,v)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

Consequently, the volume can be written as:

$$
\iint_{B}(2-u^2-v^2)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\,dudv
$$

where $B : u^2+v^2 \le 2$

Polar coordinates can now be used, and we finally have the volume:

$$
\iint_{B}(2-u^2-v^2)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\,dudv=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}(2-r^2)\frac{r}{\sqrt2}drd\theta = 0
$$

which is clearly wrong! Where do I run off the rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in $\displaystyle\int_0^2$. In fact, $u^2+v^2\leqslant2\iff\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\leqslant\sqrt2$, and therefore it should be $\displaystyle\int_0^{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: Oh dear... Thank you so, so, much! I can't accept the answer until 7 minutes have passed.

Comment: How did you find the problem so quickly?

Comment: I used to teach this stuff and it is a standard mistake.